# Is it an image file issue or size issue? HTML CSS background image question

Tags: html, css, image, background, jpeg

I keep trying to use different images as a background but I am unlucky so far in figuring out if it is an issue with the photo file size or is there something wrong with the pictures i use? Asking since i tried with one image and the background image shows and works but any other picture that I want to use will not show up or work properly even though I have looked over my code multiple times and it is correct. Here is my current code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Winston Berz</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-image: url("C:\Users\apere\OneDrive\Desktop\HTML Progress\Winston Berz\All Photos\img5.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
                min-height: 100%;
                background-size: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Navbar">
            <nav>
                <a href="Main P.html">Main</a>
                <a href="About me P.html">About Me</a>
                <a href="Contact P.html">Contact</a>
                <a href="Photos P.html">Photos</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="Main Title">
            <header>
                <h1>Winston Berz</h1>
            </header>

    </body>
</html>
```

Want to also note that I also was using a separate document for css and got the same results so this time I resorted to internal css.
Help! Please and thank you I am still relatively new to coding.

Comment: Side note: your `<div id="Main Title">` is not closed

Comment: Just for a sanity check, are the other images you're trying in the same directory?

Comment: yes Ive put all the photo files I want to use together in one folder, but the picture file that did end up working was in a my pictures folder of my pc

Comment: It might just be a pathing issue to the images you aren't getting to work. Can you put a couple more images on your local folder and try them out? If they're working too, it is probably something with your image host or pathing to the images.

Comment: Chrome blocks the local files accessing for security reason. Try using relative path

Comment: I have stepped away from my pc but I will try as soon as I get home. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you could try to clear your browser cache ([here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) is how) maybe the browser is storing previous images.

Also, you could consider creating a `<div>` and place your background images there instead of setting the image inside css.

inside the `<body>` tag you can add

```
<div class="background-images-wrapper">
<img src="image/link/path" alt="background1"><img>
</div>
```

and inside your css style sheet you add this

```
.background-images-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%:
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
```

`z-index: -1` is to make sure that your images will always stay behind the rest of your elements